# Kafka avoid duplicated unread messages

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using camel-kafka to read and send messages to the kafka cluster.

I have 15 producers (different PODs) sending messages to the same kafka topic.
There are 4 consumers (different PODs) processing those messages.

The messages take some time to be processed, so the queue could have unread messages for a time.

The messages are very simple, only a long number.

I want to prevent repeated unread messages from not being queued, thus only been processed once.

Is there a way to avoid unread repeated messages in the topic?

I already tried compacted topics, sending the messages with a key - having the same payload value. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to prevent unique producers from sending *equivalent* payloads (not duplicate), is to store and compare them before producing them to Kafka.

In other words, every producer request is unique to Kafka. The brokers will never deserialize and compare data that has been written on the entire topic. That would slow it down considerably, and therefore is the client responsibility to manage.

Compacted topic do not *prevent* writing equivalent records, it only reduces the number of unique keys in the topic, on a regular interval. It does this in background threads, rather than per-produce-request, and starts from the uncompacted "head" of the topic

The other solution would be to simply produce whatever you want, then let the consumer check if it's seen the same message data before, then skip processing. You may choose to do this with a multi-layer approach of a local hashmap, which is dumped+restored into a more persistent system (database or file) when the consumer process restarts.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
I ended up using the solution on the consumer side.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer using checkmark next to the post

Answer (score -1):

In kafka, It's called ***"Exactly Once Processing"***.
You can use for that a **transactional producers and consumers**.
Here is an [example](https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-exactly-once)

Comment: The Exactly Once Processing is not what I wanted.
In this approach, the message with the given ID is processed once ever! My use case needs that the same ID could be sent more than once.

Comment: What is the guaranty that is processed once ?
Brokers, producers and consumers could fail, so the message with the same ID could be consumed and processed twice